# $dirpath changing url when called from within wordpress file

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider, relative-url

I have a slideshow on a php page that uses `$folder = opendir($dirpath);` to access images in a folder. When I enter the url of said php file all works well, however once I call this php from inside a wordpress page it no longer accesses the image folder.

I'm guessing this is due to the fact the path changes to where the php is being called to. I just can't seem to work out what I need to replace '$dirpath' with so I can access the folder url.

The tag `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/imagefolder` accesses the folder when not inside a php tag, however I don't know know I can add this inside php tags.

I've tried:

```
$dirpath = bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/imagefolder";
$dirURL = "";
$folder = opendir($dirpath);
```

but it's not correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo):

> This always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

And checking the docs on `get_bloginfo()`, you'll see that's better to use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), so your code would be

```
$dirpath = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/imagefolder";
$folder = opendir($dirpath);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've amended the code and managed to echo $dirpath and it seems to be correct, so the issue must lie elsewhere! I'll do some more digging. Thank you.

Comment: It seems only the following will pull values through..

$dirpath = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/imagefolder;
$dirURL = "";
$folder = opendir($dirpath);

Is this because opendir will only work with absolute paths?

I can see in the generated code that it's looking at the contents of the folder, however the images won't display with the relative path.. "/var/sites/.....". I thought I could just insert the domain in front but as it's a path from the server it's incorrect.

Hope that makes sense!
Thanks

Comment: It turned out the solution  $dirpath = get_stylesheet_directory() was sufficient for my problem. I just manipulated the value it created later in the code.

`$dirURL = "http://www.webaddress.co.uk";
$picpath = substr($picpath ,"48" );
$picpath = $dirURL . $picpath;`

This replaced the /var/w/.... path with the required http address.

Thanks for your help brasofilo.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, wes :)